# "Segmentation fault" when using phpseclib

Tags: php, ssh, centos, phpseclib

I  downloaded **phpseclib-0.3.10** from http://phpseclib.sourceforge.net/

My php Version : **PHP 5.2.4**

OS : CentOS release 6.6

When I run following I am getting "Segmentation fault" at this line `$ssh->login('username', 'password')`

```
<?php
set_include_path(get_include_path() . PATH_SEPARATOR . 'phpseclib');
include('Net/SSH2.php');
$ssh=new Net_SSH2('servername');
if (!$ssh->login('username', 'password')) {
     exit('Login Failed');
}
echo $ssh->exec('pwd');
?>
```

I am unable find the reason for this issue. Could you please help me to find the reason for this.

Comment: You might not want to hear this, but PHP 5.2 is outdated and not supported anymore. Many, many fixes have been done since then; one might have fixed the segmentation fault.

Answer (score 0):

My guess: either the fsockopen() call or the stream_select() call. You can figure it out by putting die()'s in your code at successive points within login() and the functions called therein.

Looking it up...  login() calls _login():

https://github.com/phpseclib/phpseclib/blob/0.3.10/phpseclib/Net/SSH2.php#L1801

_login() calls _connect():

https://github.com/phpseclib/phpseclib/blob/0.3.10/phpseclib/Net/SSH2.php#L1817

eg. before [line 964 in Net/SSH2.php](https://github.com/phpseclib/phpseclib/blob/0.3.10/phpseclib/Net/SSH2.php#L964) add `die('this far')`. If it says "this far" then try adding it after. If you get a seg fault when it's after but not before that probably means it's the fsockopen that's to blame.

And just keep on doing that until you get the seg fault. Do a `die('this far');` before and after the stream_select and just where-ever. And then post the line you're getting it on.

Comment: Thanks neubert for the reply. I did stack trace and I see that following lines throwing Segmentation fault    Math_BigInteger->modPow() SSH2.php:1405
openssl_public_encrypt() BigInteger.php:1697

Comment: Can you post a link to your phpinfo()? Maybe put it on a pastebin and post the link. Thanks!